# Having trouble when overloading the '<' operator for a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the '<' operator so that i can use the std::map in a project. The prototype in the class definition looks like this: `bool operator<(const Vertex&);`, and the body of the function looks like this:

```
bool Vertex::operator <(const Vertex& other){
    //incomplete, just a placeholder for now
    if(px != other.px){
        return px < other.px;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and the error i'm getting is this: `/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_function.h:237:22: error: passing ‘const Vertex’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘const bool Vertex::operator<(Vertex)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`

Comment: The inequality check shouldn't make a difference, since `px < other.px` shouldn't include equal ones.

Comment: The function isn't complete, if the px are the same, I move on to the next member variable to determine the difference.

Comment: I couldn't resist to point it out in case that wasn't the case. Anyway, now that you've said that, you should just use something like `std::make_pair` or `std::tie` to group those two factors together (e.g. `std::make_pair(px, py) < std::make_pair(other.px, other.py)`) to take care of the strict weak ordering for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `operator<` overload doesn't modify the object pointed to by `this`, you should mark it as a `const` member function. That is, for the declaration, add a `const` to the end:

```
class Vertex {
  // ...
  bool operator<(const Vertex& other) const;
  // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs a `const` qualifier:

```
bool Vertex::operator <(const Vertex& other) const {
    //...
}
```

That means it can be called on `const` objects.